# Experience/Experienced: "With" or "In"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order

Very simple question this time around, folks! (Have) experience or (be) experienced both generally create a connotation of living through something and/or learning about it. The big question is which preposition follows which word, or if they change based on what concept follows them.

My closest guess is:

> I have experience / I am experienced + with + general noun (cars, animals, etc.)
>
> I have experience / I am experienced + in + field of knowledge (physics, French cuisine, etc.)

A coworker of mine believes the answer may be in word order:

> I have linguistics/teaching/computer experience.

I still feel it's possible to say experience in/with, but his addition to the argument isn't invalid whatsoever. I do think sometimes my ascertainment is totally valid (to me), and other times there seem to be giant loopholes. Can anyone give a really thorough breakdown of which prepositions to use and where?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both are correct exactly the way you used them. [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/experience_1) and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/experience) give examples for *experience in* and *experience with*, where *experience* is of course used as a noun.

Furthermore, Google Books shows extensive usage of both phrases:[26,700,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22experience+in%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) and [12,000,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22experience+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) respectively.

Comment: It's very curious to see "experience of". I've never heard that construction in my entire life!

Comment: That one was new for me too :-)

Comment: I think it's used sometimes like "That was an experience of a lifetime!"

Comment: In "experience of a lifetime", the "lifetime" is not the experience gained. The experience gained is the unspecified subject of the sentence, and it happened within an (hopefully unfinished) lifetime. So the use of "of" is a rather at an angle to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question doesn't ask about the case without a preposition, that usage is also common enough that I think it warrants including here to help ease any lingering confusion:

> **I have experience [verb]. E.g., I have experience programming databases; I also have experience teaching adults to swim.**
>
> I have experience with [general noun]. E.g., I have experience *with* heartbreak.
>
> I have experience in [field of knowledge or skill]. E.g., I have experience *in* electrical engineering.